# Can I spend all my life points to draw cards?

Tags: friday

The rules of Friday state

> If at any point you must discard a life point but do not have any
>   remaining, you lose the game.

What if I have 1 life point left, and voluntarily discard it to draw a card?

Can I do that?

The game hasn't required me to discard a non-existent life point yet (and I may gain more life before it does).

As I read this, I could go several turns at 0 life, without losing, as long as the game does not require me to spend a life point that I don't have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Friday](http://riograndegames.com/Game/399-Friday)? The current text of the [rules](http://riograndegames.com/getFile.php?id=584) does not include the passage you quoted. It seems they realized the behaviour was unusual enough to warrant clarification, and updated the rules to do so.

> If you need to pay a life token during the game and do not have any left you immediately lose the game. Having zero life points is OK, but if you need one more life token you lose the game!